# How to display the current picture above the upload field in SonataAdminBundle?

Tags: php, file-upload, symfony, symfony-sonata

I am using **SonataAdminBundle** (with Doctrine2 ORM) and I have successfully added a file upload feature to my Picture model.

I would like, on the **Show** and **Edit** pages, to display a simple `<img src="{{ picture.url }} alt="{{ picture.title }} />` tag just above the relevant form field (provided that the Picture being edited is not new, of course), so that the user may see the current photo, and decide whether to change it or not.

After hours of research, I've been unable to figure out how to do it. I suppose I need to override some template, but I'm a bit lost...
Can somebody give me a hint?

*Thank you!*

Here is the relevant section of my PictureAdmin class.

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('category', NULL, ['label' => 'Catégorie'])
        ->add('title', NULL, ['label' => 'Titre'])
        ->add('file', 'file', ['required' => false, 'label' => 'Fichier']) // Add picture near this field
        ->add('creation_date', NULL, ['label' => 'Date d\'ajout'])
        ->add('visible', NULL, ['required' => false, 'label' => 'Visible'])
        ->add('position', NULL, ['label' => 'Position']);
}

protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
{
    $showMapper
        ->add('id', NULL, ['label' => 'ID'])
        ->add('category', NULL, ['label' => 'Catégorie'])
        ->add('title', NULL, ['label' => 'Titre'])
        ->add('slug', NULL, ['label' => 'Titre (URL)'])
        ->add('creation_date', NULL, ['label' => 'Date d\'ajout'])
        ->add('visible', NULL, ['label' => 'Visible'])
        ->add('position', NULL, ['label' => 'Position']);
        // Add picture somewhere
}
```

Comment: Alternative solution: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_form_type_extension.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can easily do this on show page 
by template attribute pass on `$showmapper`

```
->add('picture', NULL, array(
    'template' => 'MyProjectBundle:Project:mytemplate.html.twig'
);
```

and inside your template you get current object so u can call get method and pull image path

```
<th>{% block name %}{{ admin.trans(field_description.label) }}{% endblock %}</th>
<td>
    <img src="{{ object.getFile }}" title="{{ object.getTitle }}" />
    </br>
    {% block field %}{{ value|nl2br }}{% endblock %}
</td>
```

To show image in edit mode you have to override `fileType` or you have to create your own customType on top of `fileType`

There is also some bundle which is having this kind of functionality 
check out this [GenemuFormBundle](http://knpbundles.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle)

Comment: This works for the show page, but is there any way to put the image above the field as per the question?

Answer (score 14):

I have managed to put the image above the field in the edit form. But my solution is a little bit specific, because I use [Vich Uploader Bundle](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/) to handle uploads, so the generation of the image url was a little bit easier thanks to bundle helpers.

Let's look at my example, a film poster field in a film entity.
This is part of my admin class:

```
//MyCompany/MyBundle/Admin/FilmAdmin.php

class FilmAdmin extends Admin {

protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
 $formMapper
     ->add('title')
 ....
     ->add('poster', 'mybundle_admin_image', array(
                'required' => false,
                ))
}
```

`mybundle_admin_image` is handled by a custom field type, that is just a child of file type by setting it's `getParent` method: (don't forget to register your type class as a service)

```
//MyCompany/MyBundle/Form/Type/MyBundleAdminImageType.php

public function getParent()
{
    return 'file';
}
```

Then I have a template that extends Sonata's default styling, and I have it included in the admin class:

```
//MyCompany/MyBundle/Admin/FilmAdmin.php

public function getFormTheme() {
    return array('MyCompanyMyBundle:Form:mycompany_admin_fields.html.twig');
}
```

And finally I have a block for my custom image type that extends the basic file type:

```
//MyCompany/MyBundle/Resources/views/Form/mycompany_admin_fields.html.twig

{% block mybundle_admin_image_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% set subject =  form.parent.vars.value %}
    {% if subject.id and attribute(subject, name) %}
        <a href="{{ asset(vich_uploader_asset(subject, name)) }}" target="_blank">
            <img src="{{ asset(vich_uploader_asset(subject, name)) }}" width="200" />
        </a><br/>
    {% endif %}
    {% set type = type|default('file') %}
    <input type="{{ type }}" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} {% if value is not empty %}value="{{ value }}" {% endif %}/>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

This causes that a 200px wide preview of image (if exists) is shown above the upload field, linked to it's full size version opening in new tab. You can customize it as you want, e.g. adding a lightbox plugin.

Answer (score 11):

you can easily do this on edit page by helpers(FormMapper->setHelps) or option "help" pass on FormMapper

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper) {
    $options = array('required' => false);
    if (($subject = $this->getSubject()) && $subject->getPhoto()) {
        $path = $subject->getPhotoWebPath();
        $options['help'] = '<img src="' . $path . '" />';
    }

    $formMapper
        ->add('title')
        ->add('description')
        ->add('createdAt', null, array('data' => new \DateTime()))
        ->add('photoFile', 'file', $options)
    ;
}
```

Comment: This is great when working with the PictureAdmin class but any idea how to make it work when PictureAdmin is embedded in another admin class, e.g. using ``$formMapper->add('linkedPicture', 'sonata_type_admin')`` from ``PageAdmin::configureFormFields()``?

Comment: @caponica You figured out how to do that...?? I am stuck at the same situation too..

Comment: Yes, I got it working. It's a while since I looked at the code but you basically have to detect when the field is embedded and then use something like http://pastebin.com/rvh65viG in your ImageAdmin class

Answer (score 4):

## Solution for Symfony3

The answer from @kkochanski is the cleanest way I found so far. Here a version ported to **Symfony3**. I also fixed some bugs.

Create a new template `image.html.twig` for your new form type (full path: `src/AppBundle/Resources/views/Form/image.html.twig`):

```
{% block image_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% set type = type|default('file') %}
        <input type="{{ type }}" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} {% if value is not empty %}value="{{ value }}" {% endif %}/>
        {% if image_web_path is not empty %}
            <img src="{{ image_web_path }}" alt="image_photo"/>
        {% endif %}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

Register the new form type template in your `config.yml`:

```
twig:
    form_themes:
        - AppBundle::Form/image.html.twig
```

Create a new form type and save it as `ImageType.php` (full path: `src/AppBundle/Form/Type/ImageType.php`):

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

/**
 * Class ImageType
 *
 * @package AppBundle\Form\Type
*/
class ImageType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'file';
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'image';
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'image_web_path' => ''
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @param FormView $view
     * @param FormInterface $form
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $view->vars['image_web_path'] = $options['image_web_path'];
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->setAttribute('image_web_path', $options['image_web_path'])
        ;
    }
}
```

If you have done this. You can just import the new `ImageType` in your entity admin class:

```
use AppBundle\Form\Type\ImageType
```

And then, finally use the new form type without any inline-html or boilerplate code in `configureFormFields`:

```
$formMapper
    ->add('imageFile', ImageType::class, ['image_web_path' => $image->getImagePath()])
;
```

Instead of `$image->getImagePath()` you have to call your own method that returns the url to your image.

### Screenshots

Creating a new image entity using sonata admin:

[image]

Editing a image entity using sonata admin:

[image]

Comment: I have issue with Symfony 3.2: Could not load type "file"
500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormRegistry.php at line 87   + 
at FormRegistry ->getType ('file') 
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormRegistry.php at line 121

Answer (score 2):

You can simple do by this way

```
    $image = $this->getSubject();
    $imageSmall = '';

    if($image){
        $container = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer();
        $media = $container->get('sonata.media.twig.extension');
        $format = 'small';
        if($webPath = $image->getImageSmall()){
            $imageSmall = '<img src="'.$media->path($image->getImageSmall(), $format).'" class="admin-preview" />';
        }
    }

   $formMapper->add('imageSmall', 'sonata_media_type', array(
      'provider' => 'sonata.media.provider.image',
      'context' => 'default',
      'help' => $imageSmall
   ));
```

Comment: Fast, but dirty. :D

Answer (score 0):

Teo.sk wrote the method of showing images using VichUploader. I found an option which allow you to show images without this bundle.

First we need to create our form_type. There is tutorial: [symfony_tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html)

In main Admin class:

```
namespace Your\Bundle;

//.....//

class ApplicationsAdmin extends Admin {

//...//

public function getFormTheme() {
    return array_merge(
        parent::getFormTheme(),
        array('YourBundle:Form:image_type.html.twig') //your path to form_type template
    );

protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
     $formMapper->add('file_photo', 'image', array(
            'data_class' => 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File',
            'label' => 'Photo',
            'image_web_path' => $this->getRequest()->getBasePath().'/'.$subject->getWebPathPhoto()// it's a my name of common getWebPath method
        ))
        //....//
        ;
}

}
```

Next part is a code from ImageType class.

```
namespace Your\Bundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Options;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;


class ImageType extends AbstractType
{

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'file';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'image';
    } 

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'image_web_path'         => ''
        ));
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $view->vars['image_web_path'] = $options['image_web_path'];
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
             ->setAttribute('image_web_path', $options['image_web_path'])
        ;
    }
}
```

And on the end time for image_type twig template.

```
{% block image_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% set type = type|default('file') %}
    <input type="{{ type }}" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} {% if value is not empty %}value="{{ value }}" {% endif %}/>
    <img src="{{ image_web_path }}" alt="image_photo"/>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

For me it's working! I'm also using avalanche bundle to resize images.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way - but you will see the picture below the upload button.
SonataAdmin lets put raw HTML into the ‘help’ option for any given form field. You can use this functionality to embed an image tag:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper) {

    $object = $this->getSubject();

    $container = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer();

    $fullPath =     $container->get('request')->getBasePath().'/'.$object->getWebPath();


    $formMapper->add('file', 'file', array('help' => is_file($object->getAbsolutePath() . $object->getPlanPath()) ? '<img src="' . $fullPath . $object->getPlanPath() . '" class="admin-preview" />' : 'Picture is not avialable')

}
```